# PDFBox child cannot be cast as a PDField in version 1.8.9

Tags: pdfbox

I am using PDFBox to populate fields in PDF Files.  I am currently using version 1.6.0 and the code works.  I tried to update to version 1.8.9 and the child elements are not being seen as a PDField.  The "kid instanceof PDField" always returns false and if I try to cast it as a PDField I get "Cannot cast 'org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotationWidget' to 'org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDField'".  The code works fine on the older version.  Do I need to handle this differently in the newer version of PDFBox?  Fields that do not have children elements work fine.  In this case the same field is displayed in 2 locations on the PDF.

```
List<COSObjectable> kids = field.getKids();
    if (kids != null) {
        if (!parent.equals(field.getPartialName())) {
            parent = parent + "." + field.getPartialName();
        }
        for (COSObjectable kid : kids) {
            if (kid instanceof PDField) {
                processField(result, pages, (PDField) kid, parent);
            }
        }
```

Comment: could you post a link to the PDF?

Comment: Here is a link to the file (https://drive.google.com/a/cuprodigy.com/file/d/0B-oNlBMuGWspaFR5T3lGZklPcUU/view?usp=sharing)  The field causing me issues is named APP1_FULL_NAME

Comment: I clicked on "get permission" 5 hours ago and again now.

Comment: Got it. Is this file confidential?

Comment: The child elements are indeed of type PDAnnotationWidget. Why care? You can set their parent, i.e. AP1_FULL_NAME. I just did this with Adobe Reader and it is what happens. The widget children aren't touched.